# Watch a large video file on a TV screen via HDMI

Tags: hdmi, tv

I am planning to buy a TV screen for a reasonable price (don't know which one yet). I have on my laptop large video files (+- 7GB per file, 1080p, 5000 to 10000 kbps) and I would like to know if an HDMI cable is enough to watch those videos on any TV screen (that has an HDMI spot obviously). Basically, I don't want my videos to lag. They can play just fine on my laptop and I use VLC.
I guess my question is, does it need to be a specific type of TV screen or does any one work?

Comment: It depends on the Specs of the video card is how the picture is going to run. Just a bit to add there. I run most off my desktop on 1080p with no issues on a 1gb graphic card either through hdmi or chromecast.

Comment: So KingPin, are you saying the graphic card from the TV has to be around 1gb? Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: @c7ludovic The TV doesnt have a GPU per say. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If the laptop can play them back fine on its own then playback on the TV will be identically smooth when you use it instead of the laptops own screen.

The only potential issue is when you use BOTH screens simultaneously, eg browser on the laptop and movie on the TV, that **may** tax the laptop but its unlikely.

Comment: And you have independant screens - I'd guess switching off one screen or mirroring won't be additional load.